# is there a way to search each element in a collection c#

Tags: c#, collections

I have a collection of objects and inside of each object I have a boolean property. Is there any way of searching the collection and getting a count of how many properties is set to true? thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var count = list.Count(x => x.boolValue);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked just as needed. Just as a quick not. Can you explain the count method and the => symbol please. Thanks!

Comment: => symbol means lambda expression - Count method iterates collection and increases it's value if expression returns true - so if boolValue of element is true it increases. You can write more complex expressions. For example: list.Count(x => x.id %2 == 0) returns count of elements with even ids.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is pretty vague but here is one way to do it with LINQ:

```
var trueCount = someCollection.Count(item => item.someBoolean);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this but using linq is pretty terse:

```
using System.Linq;
int trueCount = myCollection.Count(item => item.prop);
```

MSDN Enumerable.Count: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181.aspx